# NameError when Passing Variable to a Class Instance in Python

Tags: python

working on a sample battleship game project in python

created a ship class for the various ships here

```
class Ship:

def __init__(self, ship_name, size, coordinates, direction):
    self.ship_name = ship_name
    self.size = size
    self.coordinates = coordinates
    self.direction = direction
```

here is my core battleship.py file:

```
from ship import Ship

SHIP_INFO = [
    ("Aircraft Carrier", 5),
    ("Battleship", 4),
    ("Submarine", 3),
    ("Cruiser", 3),
    ("Patrol Boat", 2)
]

BOARD_SIZE = 10

VERTICAL_SHIP = '|'
HORIZONTAL_SHIP = '-'
EMPTY = 'O'
MISS = '.'
HIT = '*'
SUNK = '#'

board=[]
for row in range(10):
    board.append('O'*10)


def clear_screen():
    print("\033c", end="")


def print_board_heading():
    print("   " + " ".join([chr(c) for c in range(ord('A'), ord('A') + BOARD_SIZE)]))


def print_board(board):
    print_board_heading()
    row_num = 1
    for row in board:
        print(str(row_num).rjust(2) + " " + (" ".join(row)))
        row_num += 1


def coord_prompt():
    while True:
        coords = input("Where do you want the ship + (example: A1)?: ")
        coords_strip = coords.strip()
        coords_lower = coords_strip.lower()
        x = coords_lower[0]
        y = coords_lower[1:]

        if (len(x)+len(y)) in range(2,4):
            if x not in 'abcdefghij' or y not in '1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10':
                print("Oops!  That was not a valid entry.  Try again...")
                continue

            else:
                return x,y
        else:
            if len(coords_lower) < 2 or len(coords_lower) > 3:
                print("Oops!  That's too not the right amount of characters. Please try again...")
                continue


def pos_prompt():
    while True:
        dir = input("[H]orizontal or [V]ertical?")
        dir_strip = dir.strip()
        dir_lower = dir_strip.lower()

        if dir_lower not in 'hv':
            print("Oops!  That was not a valid entry.  Try again...")
            continue

        else:
            return dir_lower


def make_ships(player):
    ships = []
    for ship, size in SHIP_INFO:
        coord_prompt()
        pos_prompt()
        ships.append(Ship(ship, size, (x, y), dir_lower))
    return ships

player1 = input("What's Player 1's Name? ")
player2 = input("What's Player 2's Name? ")
print("\n")
print_board(board)
print("\n")

# define player one's fleet
make_ships(player1)
```

i'm getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/chrisstuart/Desktop/battleship/battleship/battleship.py", line 91, in <module>
    make_ships(player1)
  File "C:/Users/chrisstuart/Desktop/battleship/battleship/battleship.py", line 81, in make_ships
    ships.append(Ship(ship, size, (x, y), dir_lower))
NameError: name 'x' is not defined
```

I just don't understand why the returned x and y variables from the coord_prompt function are not passing to the ship instance of Ship when running the make_ships function.  I assumed it was a problem with the way that I had formatted some of the if statement and the while loop and tried a few variations but still getting same error.

Comment: its your `coord_prompt()` line, you're not getting the return values, try this instead:
`x, y = coord_prompt()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you haven't captured the return values in the calling function in order to use them in the subsequent call.

The names `x` and `y` are *local* to `coord_prompt` and are not preserved once that function finishes. The values are returned, but you still need to assign them to something. The same is true of the value returned from `pos_prompt`.

```
    x, y = coord_prompt()
    dir_lower = pos_prompt()
    ships.append(Ship(ship, size, (x, y), dir_lower))
```

Comment: Thank you!  Very helpful.  Quick question--if i want to get the name of the ship into the coord_prompt function -- coords = input("Where do you want the ship + (example: A1)?: ")  is there an easy way to do that?

Comment: Sure, you would need to make the name a parameter to the coord_prompt function.